# 'date' on a command issued before midnight but ending after midnight. Today or tomorrow date?

Tags: date, zip

I will be launching today a zip command naming the new file with the current date (`date+\%Y\-%m\-%d`.zip).
The compression will probably end after midnight.
Do you think the zip will be named with today's date or tomorrow's?

Command is:

```
zip -9 -m -o /path/file_name`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.zip /path/tmp/*
```

Comment: Show your command, it depends when filename will be generated

Comment: zip -9 -m -o /path/file_name`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.zip /path/tmp/*

Comment: @LeonidMew Thanks for editing the question and inserting the command from the comment. Daniel Foti, that's what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It will have todays date. The date command is run when the command is issued.

Actually, the nested command `$(date ...)` will be executed by the shell before the `zip` command is called. This is called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), the nested command will be replaced by its output.